# How to generate sef url in joomla3.1 component

Tags: url-routing, joomla3.1

How to generate sef url in joomla3.1 component?
My route is here.

```
my_component/view/categories/category/catID/itemID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you would use something like the following:

```
echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=categories&catid=20&Itemid=50');
```

Joomla will automatically turn this into a SEF URL using the `JRoute()` class.

For more information on supporting SEF URL's with your component, have a read of this:

http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Hope this helps